# Excel to PowerPoint using Office Javascript API

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I'm developing add-in that copies data from Excel to PowerPoint for Office (office.js) but I can't get the opened PowerPoint presentation to write in it. I know that in the past it was not possible, but I thought that they improved the API, I have read the documentation, but I cannot find any solution. Have anyone from idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that. Office web add-ins work for the currently opened document/presentation only and run in the browser sandbox where you can't perform IO operations with local files except the sandbox. Instead, you may consider making a web API call where you could use the Open XML SDK for editing files on the server side. Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [Understand when and how to use Office Open XML in your Word add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml)
- [Work with workbooks using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks)

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what your scenario is, but if the Excel workbook is stored on a SharePoint or OneDrive folder, you can have an add-in in PowerPoint use the Microsoft Graph APIs to open it and get data and paste the data into the open PowerPoint document. This sample does that: [PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart).